# Site with a width of 1044px doesn't fit on an iPad

Tags: css, wordpress, ipad, width, viewport

I'm developing a site using WordPress. The site is centered and 1044 pixels wide. On desktop browsers everything works as expected, but when I check it on an iPad, the design is cut off on the right (using either iPad orientation) and I have to swipe to see it all.

http://oscarciutat.com/reciclar/home/

I added this CSS rule with no success:

```
body {
    min-width: 1044px;
}
```

If I add the following meta tag the problem worsens:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong here? Every solution I try doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <!-- You can change the initial-scale to make it fit --->
```

Try using the above, that should make it work.

If not, you could use CSS media queries for the iPad screen resolution

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {  
  YOUR CSS TO REDUCE WIDTH OF SITE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The iPad3 does indeed have a much higher resolution, but they all work with 1024x768 as viewport. Thats why it won't fit.

Comment: Isn't the iPad supposed to zoom automatically to fit the site in its screen?

Comment: It will never go wider then 1024px's